# How to display Local Notification in Background

Tags: react-native, audio, notifications, expo

I am trying to set up a local notifications with certain time to pushed for user when the time arrives. 
I want help in two steps :

1) How to let that notifications fired while the app is in Background

2) How to add a sound to notifications when fired

Also I want to know if the approach I am using is right ?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, Vibration, Platform , Alert} from 'react-native';
import {Notifications} from 'expo';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';



const LocalNotificationsScreen = () => {

  const [notification, setNotification] = useState({});


    useEffect(() => {
        askPermissions();
    }, []);


    let Times = [
      {time: '3:16' , name : 'test1'}, {time : '0:7', name : 'test2'},
      {time : '0:9', name : 'test3'}, {time : '2:8' , name : 'test4'},
      {time : '3:37' , name : 'test5'} , {time : '3:39', name : 'test6'}
    ];


    const askPermissions = async () => {
        const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;
        if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
          const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
          finalStatus = status;
        }
        if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      };

      const localNotification = {
        id : 1,
        title : 'Testing',
        body : 'The body ',
        data: { name : 'This is the data'},
        ios : {
          sound : true,
          _displayInForeground  : true
        },
        android : {
          name  : 'Sound',
          sound : true,
          vibrate : [ 0, 250, 250, 250 ],
          repeat : false
        },
        userText: 'Hi from Notfications'
      }


     const  schedulingOptions = {
        time : (new Date()).getTime() + 5000,
      }

      console.log((new Date()).getTime())

      const currentTime = `${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}`;
      console.log(currentTime);



     const pushTime = () => {
       return Times.map((t) => {
        if (t.time === currentTime) {
          let notificationId =
         Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification, schedulingOptions);
         console.log(notificationId);
         setTimeout(function () {
          Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync()
         }, 8000);
        }
      })
     }

     pushTime();




      Notifications.addListener(
        notification => {
          Vibration.vibrate();
          console.log(notification);
          setNotification(notification);
        }
      )

    return (
        <View>
           <Text>LocalNotifications </Text>
        </View>
    );
}


export default LocalNotificationsScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea with expo but I have used local notifications in my app by using this package..
Check local notifications section... I hope it will work with expo..
 https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Answer (score -2):

You can use notification schedule of react-native-firebase:
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/notifications/scheduling-notifications.md

- Install and setup react-native-firebase
- create notification and schedule as below
- Create a `notificationListener` to listen and trigger to show notification.
- Setup a schedule notification `firebase.notifications().scheduleNotification(notification, {
      fireDate: date.getTime(),
  })`, `notificationListener` will be triggered when `fireDate` comes

  - `.setSound(channel.sound)` set sound for notification

```js
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

// Build notification
const notificationListener = firebase
    .notifications()
    .onNotification(notification => {
      const {title, body, data} = notification;
      console.log('onNotification:', notification);
      if (typeof onNotification == 'function')
        onNotification(title, body, data);
      const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
        sound: 'sound',
        show_in_foreground: true,
        show_in_background: true,
      })
        .setSound(channel.sound)
        .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setBody(body)
        .setData(data)
        .android.setChannelId('@string/default_notification_channel_id') // e.g. the id you chose above
        .android.setSmallIcon('@mipmap/ic_launcher') // create this icon in Android Studio
        .android.setColor('#000000') // you can set a color here
        .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

      firebase
        .notifications()
        .displayNotification(localNotification)
        .then(() => {
          cancelNotification(notification.notificationId);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });

// Schedule the notification for 1 minute in the future
const date = new Date();
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 1);

firebase.notifications().scheduleNotification(notification, {
    fireDate: date.getTime(),
})
```

Comment: Thank you all for everyone whom tried to help. The issue that my code is working well as mentioned in my question. I needed just to find a way how it can work in background the other issue that I am building my app using EXPO so I can not use (react-native-firebase) library for notifications